# ProcessDebugPort and IsDebugPresent results don't match

Tags: winapi, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to use `NtQueryInformationProcess()` with `ProcessDebugPort`.
But when I run under a debugger, I get 0 instead of a nonzero result.

However, when I use `IsDebuggerPresent()`, I get 1 (nonzero) as a result.

The full line is:

```c
DWORD debugPort = NULL;
NtQueryInformationProcess(procH, ProcessDebugPort, &debugPort, sizeof(debugPort), NULL);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `debugPort` is 0 after call `NtQueryInformationProcess` and it return 0 ?

Comment: Yes, both debugPort and ntstatus 0.

Comment: may be you use wrong `procH` value or something else. also `DWORD_PTR DebugPort` must be - in 64bit process you go error here

Comment: An `NTSTATUS` value of 0 is `STATUS_SUCCESS`, so the function is successful, it just didn't have a port to output.  Also, the last parameter of `NtQueryInformationProcess()` is not documented as accepting a NULL pointer, so you should pass in a valid pointer for it to output to: `DWORD_PTR debugPort = 0; ULONG outSize = 0; NtQueryInformationProcess(procH, ProcessDebugPort, &debugPort, sizeof(debugPort), &outSize);`

Comment: First line in the documentation for [NtQueryInformationProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntqueryinformationprocess): *"`NtQueryInformationProcess` may be altered or unavailable in future versions of Windows. Applications should use the alternate functions listed in this topic."* You already know what the alternatives are. Why aren't you using those?